# how to echo a populated php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email, loops

I have this code:

```
<?php 
$result_array1 = array();
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  `test_thing`";
$result1 = mysql_query("$sql1") or die($sql1.mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
       $result_array1[] = $row1['email'];
    }
$sentmail = mail($result_array1,$subject,$message,$header);
?>
```

My problem is that if I place the mail function inside the loop, the user receives many emails instead of one, and if I place it out of the loop, no email is sent. My aim is to send only 1 email to each user, but that email should containt in it many mixed emails. I have read in other forums that it can be done using arrays. Maybe there is a mistake with the codes. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: @Shedal It could be, but by default `mysql_fetch_array()` gets _both_ associative and numeric keys so this works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php 
$result_array1 = array();
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  `test_thing`";
$result1 = mysql_query("$sql1") or die($sql1.mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
       $result_array1[] = $row1['email'];
    }
$email = implode(",",$result_array1); // $email = "one@example.com,two@example.com,three@example.com"
$sentmail = mail($email,$subject,$message,$header);
?>
```

The first parameter of the `mail` can be a single email id or email ids separated by commas. Which means you can send the email to multiple users just using one function call.

Comment: in question it is writter "My aim is to send only 1 email to each user"

Comment: @MoyedAnsari: It will send **only one email to each user**

Comment: what if the query returns the two exactly same email addresses ?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari: what are you trying to prove ? try to understand the need of the questioner. Dont make silly aruguments

Comment: what im saying that $result_array1 may has two identical emails, since there is no distinct or group by in query.

Comment: @MoyedAnsari: I saw ur answer with the group by statement. But that is not the main hurdle of the questioner. If you are that much caring, what if one email is null ? or what if one email is not a  valid one ?

Comment: <?php 
$result_array1 = array();
$result_array2 = array();
$result_array3 = array();
$result_array4 = array();
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  `test_thing`";
$result1 = mysql_query("$sql1") or die($sql1.mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
       $result_array1[] = $row1['email'];
       $result_array2[] = $subject;
       $result_array3[] = $message;
       $result_array4[] = $header;
    }
$email = implode(",",$result_array1);
$sentmail = mail($email,$result_array2,$result_array3,$result_array4);
?>


Is there anything wrong with those codes?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM  `test_thing`
```

It will return only unique e-mail addresses from the table. That way you can use the `mail()` in the loop and not worry about duplicated e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

According to php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

mail accepts a string for the to address. You could always `implode(',', $result_array1)`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO $to parameter in mail function just one email support .if you want send to many email, change your $headers and set Bcc;
sample code:

```
$headers.="Bcc: "; 
while($count < $count_recip){ 
$headers.=$recip[$count].", "; 
$count ++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$result_array1 = array();
$sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  `test_thing` GROUP BY `user_id`";
$result1 = mysql_query("$sql1") or die($sql1.mysql_error());

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $result_array1[] = $row1['EmailAddress'];
}

$email = implode(",",$result_array1);
```

I modified some of the answers together.

There will be no duplicate emails either, atleast there wasn't for me.

Comment: If you're only using EmailAddress from the result set, then you can just `SELECT DISTINCT EmailAddress FROM ....`, which will guarantee that you don't get duplicate entries for EmailAddress.